# Stuck with promises

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I have array of projects and array of dates, mapping dates then projects, I'm making API calls for reports URLs
I need to collect array of objects with urls and corresponding name-date of the projects if data exists and i receive the URL
With my current code I receive array of objects with promises...

```
  const getURL = async url => {
    try {
      await fetch(url, {method: 'GET', headers: headers_data})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => data.urls[0]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error getting links', error);
    }
  };
```

```
 let linksToDownload = [];
 await Promise.all(dateOfReport.map(async (date) => {
     await Promise.all(apps.map(async (appId) => {
      const API = process.env.API + appId + "&date=" + date ;
      let url = getURL(API)
      let obj = {
        name: date + "appId" + appId,
        value: url,
      }
      return linksToDownload.push(obj);
    }));
    return;
  }));

  console.log(linksToDownload);
```

My current log is

```
[
  { name: '2020-04-29appIdda555', value: Promise { <pending> } },
  { name: '2020-04-29appIdqqq444', value: Promise { <pending> } },
  { name: '2020-04-30appIdda555', value: Promise { <pending> } },
  { name: '2020-04-30appIdqqq444', value: Promise { <pending> } }
]
```

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: How about you 'await' getData (API)?

Comment: `getURL` doesn't `return` anything, even if you `await` it you won't get any result…

Comment: Yes, you are right @deceze. The fetch call inside getURL (which is incorrectly mapped as getData) should return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You're just missing an await in</del>

```
let url = getData(API);
```

– that should be

```
let url = await getData(API);
```

I'd maybe refactor things like this:

```
// Simply get some JSON from an URL.
async function getJSON(url) {
  const resp = await fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: headers_data });
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

// Get the first report URL for a given app ID and date.
// TODO: error handling is missing
async function getReportURL(appId, date) {
  const apiUrl = process.env.API + appId + "&date=" + date;
  const data = await getJSON(apiUrl);
  const url = data.urls[0];
  return {
    name: date + "appId" + appId,
    value: url,
  };
}

// Iterate over date and app arrays to get an array of promises...
const linkPromises = [];
dateOfReport.forEach(date => {
  apps.forEach(appId => {
    // NB: not using `await` here, so the requests will
    //     happen in parallel here.
    linkPromises.push(getReportURL(appId, date));
  });
});

// Await all the promises to get the final result.
const links = await Promise.all(linkPromises);

console.log(links);
```

Comment: First of all thanks, i tried that one, getting undefined
Error getting links TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
`
[
{ name: '2020-04-29appIdqqw444', value: undefined },
  { name: '2020-04-30appIdqqw444', value: undefined },
  { name: '2020-04-30appIddd55', value: undefined },
  { name: '2020-04-29appIdd55', value: undefined }
]
`

Comment: @Igor See my refactored answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly if data exists for this date or correct project name. Am I right, that 'undefined' values in links array, if no data or any error I should remove after?

Comment: That'd be easiest, sure.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me to proceed!!